# React - Uncaught Type Error data.map is not a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So I have this bit of code - and I think it works well. I'm hitting the database on cli and I see exactly what I'd like to see. However, the .map function isn't working. I don't see how it wouldn't work considering I'm explicitly rendering it as .json from the axios.get and also from the controller level (React on Rails). I don't see where this is losing it's array type.

```
const Restaurants = () => {
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {
    axios.get('/api/v1/restaurants.json')
    .then( resp => setRestaurants(resp.data) )
    .catch( resp => console.log(resp) ) 
}, [])

const grid = restaurants.map( (restaurant, index) => {
    return (
        <Restaurant
        key={index}
        attributes={restaurant.data.attributes} <--- delete data
        />
    )
})
```

EDIT:
Delete "data" from restaurant.data.attributes and we're good to go.

Comment: Could you log your resp inside then block also and see if you're getting the data field inside that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? This is actually my first go at React so I'm new to all of this axios.get/.then/.catch mumbo jumbo.

Comment: `.then(resp => { console.log(resp.data); setRestaurants(resp.data); })`

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed at all. It's still giving me a type error.

Comment: I just wanted you to see the output in console as in what type of data are you getting?

Comment: Getting the array, the exact array that I'm looking for with the corresponding data from it's model.

Comment: `data.map` isnt found on this code snippet. So where is `data` coming from ?

Comment: You are correct kind sir. Will update question, to include the answer. Thanks for your generous contribution @BARNOWL

Comment: any luck on this yet ?

Comment: @BARNOWL Yes, question was updated to reflect the corrected snippet. I was calling .data in there unnecessarily.